# A question about certain sets of permutations of the ordered pairs $(1,1),(1,2),\cdots,(1,n),\cdots,(n,1),(n,2),\cdots,(n,n)$

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $n>1$ be a given positive integer. For any $0\leq k\leq n^2$, let $A_k$ be the set of permutations $((i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),\cdots,(i_{n^2},j_{n^2}))$ of the ordered pairs $(1,1),(1,2),\cdots,(1,n),\cdots,(n,1),(n,2),\cdots,(n,n)$ satisfying $i_1\leq i_2\leq \cdots\leq i_k$ and  $j_{k+1}\leq j_{k+2}\leq \cdots\leq j_{n^2}$.

For any $$((i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),\cdots,(i_k,j_k),(i_{k+1},j_{k+1}),\cdots,(i_{n^2},j_{n^2}))\in A_k,$$ we have $$((j_{k+1},i_{k+1}),(j_{k+2},i_{k+2}),\cdots,(j_{n^2},i_{n^2}),(j_1,i_1),(j_2,i_2),\cdots,(j_k,i_k))\in A_{n^2-k}.$$
So it is easy to see that $\vert A_k\vert=\vert A_{n^2-k}\vert$ for any $0\leq k\leq [n^2/2]$.

> Question: Do we have that $\vert A_0\vert<\vert A_1\vert<\cdots<\vert A_{[n^2/2]}\vert$?

Comment: $S_n$ does not have $n^2$ elements.

Comment: I do not understand the definition of $A_k$. As written, $A_k$ consists of $n^2$-tuples of certain kind of pairs, not of permutations.

Comment: Every element of $A_k$ is a permutation of $S_n$.

Comment: It is extremely confusing to use $S_n$ to denote a set whose members are being permuted rather than the symmetric group on $n$ letters.

Comment: @BorisBukh: whether you consider the elements of $A_k$ as tuples or permutations is not so important because the question is about the cardinality of the $A_k$.

Comment: Do you mean that the permutations are cycles of length $n^2$?

Comment: Chris Ramsey:Sorry, I don't quite understand your meaning.

Comment: @user173856 In what specific way is this a permutation of the set $W_n$? Could you perhaps rewrite your definition of $A_k$ in an alternate manner?

Comment: I am sorry! I just modified my question. My expression was not clear before.

Comment: @user173856: To denote permutation as a single object, it needs to be enclosed into parentheses, e.g., we write (3,4,2,1) instead of just 3,4,2,1. I've just made this change to your question.

Comment: Max Alekseyev：But for the set $\{(i,j):1\leq i,j\leq n^2\}$, $((i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),\cdots,(i_{n^2},j_{n^2}))$ also denote a cycle, would not they be mixed up?

Comment: @user173856: you call it permutation, not cycle -- I do not see any confusion here.

Comment: Another way to define it: $|A_k|$ is the number of $n\times n$ matrices with entries $1,\ldots,n^2$ (once each), such that $1,\ldots,k$ are in row order and $k+1,\ldots,n^2$ are in column order.

Comment: Better to call it a linear order of the $n^2$ pairs than a permutation. $(abcd)$ and (cdab)$ are equal as permutations.

Comment: $A_{0} = (n!)^n$ (trivial), $A_{1} = n(n!)^n$ (provable), $A_{2} = (n!)^n (n^2+n-1)/2$ (conjecture; must be provable too). It gets very messy with $k\ge 3$.

Comment: Btw, this property is called unimodality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE (2022-07-13)**. The generating function for $A_k$ can be expressed as
$$\sum_{k\geq0} A_k t^k = {\cal L}_{x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n} \sum_{\lambda} e_{\lambda}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\cdot m_{\bar\lambda}(y_1,\dots,y_n)\cdot t^{\mathrm{sum}(\lambda)},$$
where summation is done over all partitions $\lambda$ whose Young tableau fits the $n\times n$ square; $\bar\lambda$ is the partition whose Young tableau complements that of $\lambda$ in the $n\times n$ square; $e$ and $m$ are elementary and monomial symmetric polynomials respectively; and $\cal L$ is the Laplace transform evaluated at $1$, which replaces each $x_i^d$ or $y_j^d$ with $d!$.

With this formula I was able to extend computations and confirm the conjecture for $n\leq 10$. The data is uploaded to [OEIS A261602](http://oeis.org/A261602) and [OEIS A261603](http://oeis.org/A261603).

Below is my original answer presenting data for $n\leq 6$.

---

I've computed values of $|A_k|$ for $0\leq k\leq \lfloor n^2/2\rfloor$ and $n\leq 6$:

$n=1:$ 1

$n=2:$ 4, 8, 10

$n=3:$ 216, 648, 1188, 1668, 1944

$n=4:$ 331776, 1327104, 3151872, 5695488, 8608896, 11446272, 13791744, 15326208, 15858432

$n=5:$ 24883200000, 124416000000, 360806400000, 787138560000, 1426595328000, 2262299258880, 3240594432000, 4283587584000, 5304730521600, 6222411878400, 6968709089280, 7493189990400, 7763310604800

$n=6:$ 139314069504000000, 835884417024000000, 2855938424832000000, 7259810955264000000, 15220062093312000000, 27765294052147200000, 45532546213478400000, 68600569724928000000, 96440964380098560000, 127985462154362880000, 161777817980986982400, 196164002436769382400, 229476155622594969600, 260178812386069708800, 286962944406552576000, 308788668410898677760, 324887962565624463360, 334743605500457779200, 338060641751949312000

So the conjecture is confirmed numerically for $n\leq 6$.

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to compute the values of $\vert A_k\vert$ for $n=6$?

Comment: @user173856: I've just extended my computation to $n=6$.

Answer (score 7):

This is not an answer, but perhaps a relevant thought. The combinatorial description of $A_k$, for $0\le k\le n^2$, together with the Gamma integral $\Gamma(n+1)=\int_0^{\infty}x^ne^{-x}dx$ leads to the generating function
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n^2} A_kt^k=\int_0^\infty\cdots \int_0^{\infty}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)}\prod_{i,j=1}^n(x_i+ty_j)dx_1dy_1\cdots dx_ndy_n.$$
A polynomial whose coefficients form a unimodal (resp. log-concave) sequence is called a unimodal (resp. log-concave) polynomial. It is known that a polynomial with real roots is log-concave and thus unimodal. So unimodality holds for the polynomial being integrated above. Unfortunately log-concavity or unimodality are not preserved under linear combinations so one can't conclude the desired property just from the integral representation above. Maybe someone with knowledge in analysis will find this wording more useful.

Comment: Gjergji Zaimi：Your answer is very useful！Thank you very much！

Comment: Possible bad news for this strategy: $\sum A_k t^k$ does not have real roots. Using Max Alekseyev's numbers, all the roots of $4 x^4 + 8 x^3 + 10 x^2 + 8 x + 4$ are complex. On the other hand, his data is consistent so far with the coefficients being log concave.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer But all the roots have $\Re(z) < 0$, so it is real-stable, which means there might be more to this strategy?